# Dynamically change row and column size in grid based in css/React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, datagrid, css-grid

I'm trying to dynamically resize a column / row in a grid based on the content displayed. The columns and rows all seem to have the same size no matter what content is displayed.

I want no gaps/ spaces between the tweets.[image]
[image: grid]

This is the styling code that I have:

```
import { Grid } from "@nextui-org/react";
import React from "react";
import TweetTest from "../components/Tweet";
import { useGetTweetsQuery } from "../generated/graphql";

interface tweetProps {}

const Tweet: React.FC<tweetProps> = ({}) => {
  const { data } = useGetTweetsQuery();
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr))",
        gridTemplateRows: "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr))",
        gridAutoFlow: "row dense",

        gridColumnGap: "32px",
        margin: "0 200px",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignContent: "end",
      }}
    >
      {data && data.getTweets && (
        <>
          {data.getTweets.map((tweet) => (
            <div
              key={tweet.id}
              className={`${
                tweet.media &&
                (tweet.media.length > 0 || tweet.text.length > 100
                  ? "col-span-1 row-span-3"
                  : "col-span-1")
              }`}
            >
              <TweetTest tweet={tweet} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tweet;
```